# How make security storage that works with file protocol?

Tags: storage, disk-encryption

There is some system that stores report files in a local folder.
Information security department wants these reports to be stored not on the local server, but in a remote secured storage and that the data is encrypted.
The problem is that on the server where the system is deployed, access to these reports works only through the file protocol.
What can be used to implement this?

Comment: A network share, mounted where that tool saves its reports sounds about right. Are you the person who would be responsible for said "remote secured storage" or is that someone else?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, I'm not responsible for said this. My coworkers from IS department wants some kind of encryption and security access. What can I use for this?

Comment: Then you just need to ask them which network share technologies they offer (SMB/CIFS, NFS, Ceph Drive…) and mount that. What you can use isn't your decision!